# How can I pull an object's data into an event handler

Tags: java, object, scope

I am trying to bring a String from an Item object named pt created in the class ReadAndSearch into the event class.  I have not been able to get the program to return data, only NULL for the object's time field.  There is data in the object's fields in the ReadAndSearch class.  The error occurs where the <<== notes are shown.  This is my first program in Java, I am learning as I go here.  I am not sure what I have missed and cannot find it searching the Java 7 API or from Googling.  Below are the three classes involved; Item, ReadAndSearch and Event.

```
public class Item {
private String name;
private String time;

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
    return name;
}
public String getTime() {
    return this.time;
}

public String setTime(String time){
    this.time = time;
    return time;
}
```

}

```
    public class Event implements ActionListener {          //wiring for action listener
    Item pt;                                            //Put item assignment here, I think scope is part of the problem.
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    newProductCode = parttextfield.getText();           //This is where I assign the input to a String object.
    ReadAndSearch rs = new ReadAndSearch();             //Sending keyboard input to method readIt of class ReadAndSearch
    rs.readIt(newProductCode);                          //Sending keyboard input to method readIt of class ReadAndSearch
        String t = pt.getTime();                        // <<== **This keeps pulling a NULL**
        int convertedtime = Integer.parseInt(t);        // <<== Added this line to convert String to int  **Failed
        System.out.println("If you can see this, " + convertedtime + " has been retrieved");
        timerLabel.setText(" "+ convertedtime);         //This is the first displayed element, then it is passed to TimeClass.
        TimeClass tc = new TimeClass(convertedtime);
        timer = new Timer(1000, tc);                    //tc is the actionListener the timer is waiting on.
        timer.start();
    }
}

public class ReadAndSearch {
public String line;
public String name;
public String time;
Item pt = new Item();

    public void readIt(String newProductCode){                                              //method that takes screen input.
        String findMe = newProductCode;                                                     //assign value of data passed in to the findMe variable.
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dataFile.csv")); // Open the file as a buffered reader.
        int linecount = 0;                                                      // Start a line count and declare a string to hold our current line.
        System.out.println("Searching for " + findMe + " in file...");          // Just to verify what I am searching for.
        while (( line = br.readLine()) != null) {                               // Loops through each line, stashing the line into line variable.
                linecount++;                                                    // Increment the count and find the index of the word.
                int indexfound = line.indexOf(findMe.toUpperCase());            // Convert input to case match what is in data file.
                if (indexfound > -1) {                                          // If greater than -1, means the word was found.
                                String[] parts = line.split(",");                           // Splitting file lines by comma
                                name = parts[0];                                            // Line split, this is the part number.
                                time = parts[1];                                            // Line split, this is the time allocated.
                                System.out.println(name +" was found, " + time + " seconds are allocated for completion");  //For verification of search only.
                }
        }
                    pt.setTime(time);
                    pt.setName(name);
        br.close();                                                             // Close the file after searching.
            }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
    }

    }
```

}

Comment: Why are your set methods returning values?

Comment: `"Added this line to convert String to int  **Failed"` - can you elaborate on "Failed"?

Comment: Do you get a hit when you search for the product code in the CSV file?

Comment: You never initialize your Item variable in your Event class. In order to get this value in the Event class, it either needs to be part of the event args to the actionPerformed method, or the fields in the Item class need to be static.

Comment: I don't see where the `Event` class is being used

Comment: Good morning all.  Yes, the data is pulled from the file correctly in the ReadAndSearch class.  The pt object has the correct data in it.  What I get as a return value in the Event class is a java.lang.NullPointerException.  That is what I meant in the comment **Failed

Comment: I thought that what I did on the second line of the event class was to initialize the object, not as new.